# Cannot send request to MQSeries service

Tags: queue, ibm-mq

Im trying to send request with such code

```
import com.ibm.mq.jms.*;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

public class MQSend {  
  public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            try {
            MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
            cf.setHostName("blabla");
            cf.setPort(15000);

            cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);

            cf.setQueueManager("");
            cf.setChannel("blabla");

            MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection("blabla","blabla");

            MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("blabla");

            MQQueueSender sender =  (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);


            long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;

            TextMessage message = (TextMessage) session.createTextMessage("Basic Queue Test "+ uniqueNumber);

            // Start the connection
            connection.start();
       //     sender.send(message);

            System.out.println("Sent message to Queue MyTestQueue: " + message.getText());
        //   sender.close();
            session.close();
            connection.close();
            System.out.println("Message Sent OK.\n");
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
            System.out.println("Message Send Failure\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/msg/client/commonservices/trace/Trace
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsReadablePropertyContextImpl.<clinit>(JmsReadablePropertyContextImpl.java:51)
at com.hsbc.hbfr.test.automation.tools.jrb.plugins.itm.MQSend.main(MQSend.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace
```

So issue is that java can't get appropriate jar for com/ibm/msg/client/commonservices/trace/Trace
But I even don't use such dependency in code, any suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you install MQ Client on the server?  Did you put ALL of the MQ jar files in the CLASSPATH as per the docs?  Looks like you missed at least one.